# WSO2 GR: add application artifact and lifecyle when defining new application in the GR

Tags: wso2

I have a WSO2 Goverance Registry setup conformant to this blog post http://blog.shelan.org/2013/02/application-governance-with-wso2-greg.html.

When defining a new application in the WSO2 GR using the menu: Metadata > Add > Application I would like to be able to directly add the actual application artifact (war/car file).

The selected file should then by placed in the SVN location conforming to the initial state of the lifecycle to which I will bind the application. This of course implies that I would also need to be able to directly add the lifecycle when defining a new application.

The new application form would then be something like this:

- Name: ExampleApplication-1.0.0
- Type: .war (is now redundant)
- Description: My Example Application Artifact: Selected file
- ExampleApplication-1.0.0.war Lifecyle: MyDTAP-Lifecycle_v1

Does anybody know a good starting point for adding this functionality in terms of code hooks  or extension points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, what you need to do is basically provide an file upload option in your "Application" RXT (Governance Artifact Configuration) which will upload what ever your file type and based on that you want to fill the derivable information to the meta data of the artifact. And also to attach a selected/pre defined life cycle to it at artifact creation. What you are looking for is Registry Handlers [1]. You can achieve all aforementioned tasks probably through a single handler.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Handlers

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I would vote you up if I had the reputation to do that.